# Website's performance issue

Tags: asp.net, database, performance, iis

I have an Asp.Net website with one web page whose sole purpose is receiving data in the form of a query string then separate it as required and store this data to the database.

This data comes from several Vehicle Tracking Systems. Each vehicle sends a string of data as query string every 30 seconds.

I have written the code in my webpage in such a way that as the webpage is accessed, in the page load, I read the query string and do the insert operation into the database. Something like this-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    string input = Request.QueryString["vinput"];
    var m = Regex.Match(input, @"~(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@");
    if (m.Success)
    {
        string[] vals = new string[20];
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            vals[i] = m.Groups[j].Value;
            j++;
        }
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into tracking (vehicle_no,hardware_id,lat,lng,speed,direction,an0,an1,an2,an3,di0,di1,di2,di3,do0,do1,do2,do3,tdate,ttime) values('" + vals[0] + "','" + vals[1] + "','" + vals[2] + "','" + vals[3] + "','" + vals[4] + "','" + vals[5] + "','" + vals[6] + "','" + vals[7] + "','" + vals[8] + "','" + vals[9] + "','" + vals[10] + "','" + vals[11] + "','" + vals[12] + "','" + vals[13] + "','" + vals[14] + "','" + vals[15] + "','" + vals[16] + "','" + vals[17] + "','" + vals[18] + "','" + vals[19] + "')";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I created a simulator app for testing this site in place of vehicle tracking systems. This site works fine when there is data coming from one to three simulator instances, but fails to save data to database when more than 3 simulator instances send data simultaneously(Approximately).

For example, I am sending 5 records, each one at a time from the simulator and 6 such simulator instances sending data to the page. At the end in the database I see only 15 records inserted instead of 30 records. By the way this website runs in **IIS 5.1**.

How do I deal with this issue? Suggestions please.

---

**UPDATE**: Finally found the issue. After a lot of googling found this [link](http://forums.iis.net/t/1164347.aspx) and [this](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2011/2/2/iis_request_execution_limits). Its with the server, since the request limit is only 3 for basic/starter in windows xp IIS.

Comment: It would be a good idea to see what is happening with the different petitions to your page. Try to log them to database or to a text file and see if all petitions are reaching your page and what is happening with them.

Comment: Also, IIS 5.1? The last time I've even heard someone mention IIS 5.1 had to be at least 4 years ago.

Comment: I am on XP, so couldn't help myself with a better version.

Answer (score 1):

No point in using a Page when you can use something lighter weight like a handler. You can switch a few things around, but this is not a heavy operation. Here's a pretty optimal way to do it with one exception and that would be to make a stored procedure rather than generating an insert statement from a string:

```
public class htest : System.Web.IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context)
    {
        System.Web.HttpRequest Request = context.Request;
        Match m = Regex.Match(Request.QueryString["vinput"], @"~(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@(.+)@");
        if (m.Success)
        {
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection())
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("command", con);
                    string[] vals = new string[20];
                    int j = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        vals[i] = m.Groups[j].Value;
                        j++;
                    }
                    cmd.CommandText = "insert into tracking (vehicle_no,hardware_id,lat,lng,speed,direction,an0,an1,an2,an3,di0,di1,di2,di3,do0,do1,do2,do3,tdate,ttime) values('" + vals[0] + "','" + vals[1] + "','" + vals[2] + "','" + vals[3] + "','" + vals[4] + "','" + vals[5] + "','" + vals[6] + "','" + vals[7] + "','" + vals[8] + "','" + vals[9] + "','" + vals[10] + "','" + vals[11] + "','" + vals[12] + "','" + vals[13] + "','" + vals[14] + "','" + vals[15] + "','" + vals[16] + "','" + vals[17] + "','" + vals[18] + "','" + vals[19] + "')";
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch
                {
                   //At least do some type of logging in this event.
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Success");
    }
}
```

Obviously you can use some boolean values to determine what you write back to the client at the end.

Comment: Thanks. Using Stored procedure is a good idea. The IHttpHandler is something new to me. I would quickly learn about it. So that means instead of writing the code in the page load, the above procedure would be much better in the code behind? Will that solve the issue?

Comment: You can think of a handler as something similar to a PHP or ASP script. They are very lightweight in comparison to an aspx page which has many resources it pulls together that in your case are entirely unnecessary. That being said, handlers also require more attention to detail for what you DO need because unlike an aspx page they don't come with all the bells and whistles. For instance, by default HttpHandlers do not have access to the user's Session object. Its simple to give a handler access to it, but you have to do it manually.

Comment: You can create a handler by right clicking a folder, Add New Item, then select Generic Handler. You can then implement the code I have above for that class to perform the operation. It is customary to write something back to acknowledge the Request/Post. I'll add it for reference.

Comment: That's some good info. So I create a Asp.net website, add the `.ashx` page, write the code, and let my simulators access the .ashx page. Is that the summary?

Comment: Just give me some time, working on it. Will definitely do once I am done :)

Comment: aah the same output again. Again not more than 3 simulators data is being stored in the database. Problem with the server?

Comment: Please find the update in my question. Issue with the server. By the way I have given the +1 for your better approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

few suggestions..

> You are opening connection. please close it at bottom as well. Dispose cmd object as well.
>
> Put your INSERT Ststement into a SQL Transcation
>
> USe try and Catch (USe the Catch clause to store error messages into Database , ex.message returns error detail.)

Comment: There's no point in using a SqlTransaction in this case since it's only one statement. If the statement fails, there is nothing to unwind. He should however properly dispose of the SqlConnection.